# Angular Adding items from multiple arrays into Json object

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, object

I have 3 sets of Json data

```
data1 [{id:1, systemName: "foo", moreInfo: "blah},
       {id:2, systemName: "boo", moreInfo: "blahBlah}]


data2 [{systemName: "foo",count: 21},
       {systemName: "boo",count: 454}]

data3 [{systemName: "foo",count: 643},
       {systemName: "boo",count: 674}]
```

what I require is to take the counts from data 2 and 3 and add them to their respective objects in data1 with new name like data2Count and Data3Count

so data1 would look like this:

```
data1 [{id:1, systemName: "foo", moreInfo: "blah, data2Count: 21, data3Count: 643},
       {id:2, systemName: "boo", moreInfo: "blahBlah, data2Count: 454, data3Count: 674}]
```

Currently I can only achieve this:

```
data1 [{id:1, systemName: "foo", moreInfo: "blah"}
       {id:2, systemName: "boo", moreInfo: "blahBlah"} data2Count: 454]
```

Using:

```
angular.forEach(data1, function(value1, key1) {
    angular.forEach(data2, function(value0, key0) {
        if (value1.systemName === value1.systemName) {
            $scope.sysFlow.data2Count = value1.count
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to do something like this:

```js
var data1 = [
    {id:1, systemName: "foo", moreInfo: "blah"},
    {id:2, systemName: "boo", moreInfo: "blahBlah"}
  ]


var data2 = [
    {systemName: "foo",count: 21},
    {systemName: "boo",count: 454}
  ]

var data3 = [
    {systemName: "foo",count: 643},
    {systemName: "boo",count: 674}
  ]
  
data1 = data1.map(function(obj) {

  obj.data2Count = data2.filter(function(o) {
    return o.systemName === obj.systemName
  })[0].count;

  obj.data3Count = data3.filter(function(o) {
    return o.systemName === obj.systemName
  })[0].count;

  return obj;
})

console.log(data1)
```

Comment: mm @tan few issues, well its an issure with our version of chrome that we cant use ```=>``` front end (doh) how do I edit the change th aboue to use regular ``function``` ??

Comment: Thanks very much I was missing the return haha, kept creating an array haha